# why uniq don't give non-duplicated results

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, uniq

```
find ./2012 -type f | cut -d '/' -f 5 | uniq
```

The usual filenames look like

```
./2012/NY/F/Zoe
./2012/NJ/M/Zoe
```

I suppose the command above should give non-duplicated result of file names like Zoe only for once, but it turns out not so.

Why? and how should I write to get the desired result?

Comment: `uniq` compares on a line-by-line basis, so if you get dupes, then your `cut` stuff isn't filtering out the relevant portions properly. There could also be invisible whitespace (tabs, spaces, etc...) after the names that's throwing things off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uniq` only detects duplicates if they're in consecutive lines.  The usual idiom
is to `sort | uniq` to ensure that any duplicates will appear together.

Comment: You can also use the `-u` option to `sort` to have it remove dupes as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

`uniq` requires the duplicates to be adjacent, which means you need to sort the input, which means you might as well use `sort -u`;

```
find 2012 -type f | cut -d/ -f5 | sort -u
```